# Почему создается две карты вместо одной?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, яндекс-карты

Пытаюсь сделать кластеры, но при создании одной карты появляются две: одна со всеми функциями, а другая без них, так же когда кластеризация происходит все метки дублируются скорее всего из за этих двух карт или чего то подобного.

[image: Метки дублируются и карта тоже]

```
export const AppMap = ({ marks, initialState = null, scannedCoordinate = null, officeMarks = null }: {marks: IAppMapData[], initialState: IAppMapState | null, scannedCoordinate: [string, string] | null | undefined, officeMarks: IAppMapData[] | null }) => {
const [mapState, setMapState] = useState<MapState | null>(null);
const [isAnchor, setIsAnchor] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [map, setMap] = useState<YMapsApi | null>(null);
const [marksWithIcons, setMarksWithIcons] = useState<IAppMapData[]>([]);
const [officeMarksWithIcons, setOfficeMarksWithIcons] = useState<IAppMapData[]>([]);
const [cluster, setCluster] = useState({
    layout: null
});
const mapRef = useRef(null);
const router = useRouter();
const {width} = useWindowDimensions();
const counts: any = useSelector((state ) => state.MenuState.menu[0].items);

const scrollToMap = () => {
    scroller.scrollTo('map', {
        duration: 800,
        delay: 0,
        smooth: 'easeInOutQuart'
    });
};

// Создание иконки метки
const createPlaceMarkLayout = (icon: string) => {
    if (map) {
        return map
          .templateLayoutFactory
          .createClass(
            `<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 24px; height: 24px;">
                <img src="${icon}" alt="" style="object-fit: contain;">
            </div>`
          );
    }
};
// Создание иконки метки с хинтом
const createPlaceMarkWithTextLayout = (icon: string, text: string, index: number) => {
    if (map) {
        return map
          .templateLayoutFactory
          .createClass(
            `<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 24px; height: 24px;">
                <div class='${styles['appMap__mark-info']}'>
                    <div class="${styles['appMap__mark-section']}">
                        <div class="${styles['appMap__mark-img']}">
                            ${icon ? `<img src="${icon}" alt="${text}">` : ''}               
                        </div>
                            <section class="${styles['appMap__mark-content']}">
                                <span>${text}</span>
                                <section>
                                    <span class={styles['project-item__count']}>
                                        ${counts[index].landsCount > 0 ? `${counts[index].landsCount} ${declOfNum(counts[index].landsCount, ['участок ', 'участка ', 'участков '])}`: 'Проект реализован'}
                                    </span>
                                    <span>
                                        ${counts[index].landsPriceFrom ? ` от ${numberSeparator(counts[index].landsPriceFrom)} ₽` : ''}
                                    </span>
                                </section>
                                
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <img src="${icon}" alt="" style="object-fit: contain;">
            </div>`
          );
    }
};

// Создание иконки метки
const createClusterLayout = () => {
    if (map) {
        const layout = map
          .templateLayoutFactory
          .createClass(
            `<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 24px; height: 24px;">
                <div onclick="{console.log({ properties.geoObjects.length})}" class='${styles['appMap__cluster-info']}'>
                    <div class="${styles['appMap__cluster-number']}">{{ properties.geoObjects.length}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>`
          );
        setCluster({
            layout
        });
    }
};

const instanceRef = (mapObject: any) => {
    if (mapObject) {
        mapObject.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

        if (isMobile) {
            mapObject.behaviors.disable('drag');
        } else {
            mapObject.behaviors.disable('multiTouch');
        }
    }
};

useEffect(() => {

    if (map) {
        const newMarks: IAppMapData[] = [];
        const newOfficeMarks: IAppMapData[] = [];
        marks.map((mark: IAppMapData, index: number) => {
            const iconLayout = createPlaceMarkLayout(mark.logo);
            const iconWithTextLayout = createPlaceMarkWithTextLayout(mark.logo, mark.text, index);
            newMarks.push({
                ...mark,
                iconLayout,
                iconWithTextLayout
            });
        });
        setMarksWithIcons(newMarks);
        setOfficeMarksWithIcons(newOfficeMarks);
        createClusterLayout();
    }
}, [map]);

useEffect(() => {
    const onKeypress = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            console.log('ctrlKey');
        }
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeypress);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeypress);
    };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    const multiTouch: string = width && width <= 768 ? 'multiTouch' : 'drag';
    const behaviors = ["disable('scrollZoom')", 'dblClickZoom', multiTouch];

    if (initialState) {
        setMapState({
            center: [Number.parseFloat(initialState.center.lat), Number.parseFloat(initialState.center.lng)],
            zoom: initialState.zoom,
            behaviors,
            controls: [],
        });
    } else if (marks.length > 0) {
        const firstMark: IAppMapData = marks[0];
        setMapState({
            center: [Number.parseFloat(firstMark.center.lat), Number.parseFloat(firstMark.center.lng)],
            zoom: firstMark.zoom,
            behaviors,
            controls: [],
        });
    }
}, [initialState, marks]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (scannedCoordinate) {
        setMapState({
            mapState,
            center: [Number.parseFloat(scannedCoordinate[0]), Number.parseFloat(scannedCoordinate[1])],
            zoom: 15
        });
    }
}, [scannedCoordinate]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (isAnchor) {
        setTimeout(function goToMap() {
            if (!mapRef) {
                setTimeout(goToMap, 100);
            } else {
                scrollToMap();
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}, [isAnchor]);

return mapState && (
  <div id="map" className={styles['appMap']}>
      <YMaps query={{
          load: "package.full"
      }}>
          <Map
              instanceRef={ref => instanceRef(ref)}
              onLoad={(ymaps: YMapsApi) => setMap(ymaps)}
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              position='absolute'
              state={mapState}
          >
              <Clusterer
                  options={{
                      preset: "islands#invertedVioletClusterIcons",
                      groupByCoordinates: false
                  }}
              >
              {marksWithIcons.map((mark: IAppMapData, index: number) => {
                  return (
                      <Placemark
                          key={index}
                          geometry={[Number.parseFloat(mark.point.lat), Number.parseFloat(mark.point.lng)]}
                          onMouseEnter={(e: any) => {
                              e.get('target').options.set('iconContentLayout', mark.iconWithTextLayout);
                          }}
                          onMouseLeave={(e: any) => {
                              e.get('target').options.set('iconContentLayout', mark.iconLayout);
                          }}
                          onClick={(e: any) => router.push(`/projects/${mark.path}`)}
                          options={{
                              iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
                              iconImageHref: '/images/map-icon.png',
                              iconImageSize: [64, 64],
                              iconImageOffset: [-32, -32],
                              iconContentOffset: [20, 20],
                              iconContentLayout: mark.iconLayout
                          }}
                      />
                  );})}
                  {officeMarksWithIcons.length > 0 && (
                      <>
                          {officeMarksWithIcons.map((mark: IAppMapData, index: number) => {
                              return (
                                  <Placemark
                                      key={index}
                                      geometry={[Number.parseFloat(mark.point.lat), Number.parseFloat(mark.point.lng)]}
                                      onMouseEnter={(e: any) => {
                                          e.get('target').options.set('iconContentLayout', mark.iconWithTextLayout);
                                      }}
                                      onMouseLeave={(e: any) => {
                                          e.get('target').options.set('iconContentLayout', mark.iconLayout);
                                      }}
                                      options={{
                                          iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
                                          iconImageHref: '/images/map-icon.png',
                                          iconImageSize: [64, 64],
                                          iconImageOffset: [-32, -32],
                                          iconContentOffset: [20, 20],
                                          iconContentLayout: mark.iconLayout
                                      }}
                                      properties={{
                                          balloonContent: `
                                      <img src=${mark.logo} alt=${mark.text}>
                                      <p>${mark.text}</p>
                                      <a href="/projects/${mark.path}">Больше информации...</Link>
                                  `,
                                          hintContent: `
                                      <img src=${mark.logo} alt=${mark.text}>
                                      <p>${mark.text}</p>
                                      <a href="/projects/${mark.path}">Больше информации...</Link>
                                  `,
                                      }}
                                  />
                              );
                          })}
                      </>
                  )}
              </Clusterer>
              <ZoomControl />
          </Map>
      </YMaps>
  </div>
);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две карты отображаются, скорее всего, потому что включен React.StrictMode. Попробуйте пакет `@pbe/react-yandex-maps`, там эта проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал npm run build и запустил npm run start и все стало нормально, одна карта, и метки не дублировались